# More comic book accurate portrayal of Constantine

Tags: character, arrowverse, constantine, constantine-tv

In **Arrowverse** *Matt Ryan* has played the role of demon-hunter and exorcist Constantine while in the movie it was played by *Keanu Reeves*. Which portrayal of Constantine is closer to the comics character? Which version of Constantine is more accurate to the Constantine in the comics, like the dress sense, accent, appearance, and habits, etc.?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, the Arrowverse interpretation of Constantine is far more closely aligned to the comics than the movie version. Some of the key aspects where the movie diverges:

- Constantine is from Liverpool, so Ryan's accent is far more accurate than Reeve's.
- Constantine was famously drawn specifically to look like the musician Sting, so Ryan physically resembles the character far more than Reeves.
- The comics Constantine is versed in a wide array of magics, religions, mythologies, etc. For the movie, they focused his expertise on Catholicism and the war between God and Satan.

The TV show also follows the backstory of *Hellblazer* more closely, particularly with the inclusion of his "Newcastle Crew" and their tragic end, as well as his more involved and peer-level relationship with Chas.

Comment: Shame they cancelled the show after only one season though

Comment: Which color is more accurate for his coat the black one of movies or brown one of TV series

Comment: The brown coat was what I remember most from the few comics I read.  Very cool series, though